# Visa for old dependent parents

Tags: united-states, postdocs, visa

Recently, I have been offered a postdoc position in the USA and I have been entitled to a J1 visa. I have an old mother who is entirely dependent on me. My father has passed away two years ago and there is nobody in India to look after her.

Considering her situation, can she get entitled to a J2 visa on basis of any exception? If not, what could be the best way to keep my mother with me while I work as a postdoc? Or should I drop the idea of doing the postdoc job while keeping my mother with me in the USA?

Comment: Contact a US consulate office locally for such a question. Your current university probably has the ability to do so.

Comment: https://j1visa.state.gov/basics/j2-visa/ "The J-2 Visa is a non-immigrant visa issued by a consular official at a U.S. embassy or consulate for **spouses and dependents (unmarried children under the age of 21)**" - seems pretty clear.

Comment: @BryanKrause Unfortunately, "pretty clear" rules always don't solve human problems. I've heard stories of exceptions as well. But I don't have something evident to back that. Also, in my post, I asked for the best strategy that could be adopted for my situation.

Comment: @BryanKrause, that would imply "no", but I wonder if a web page tells the whole story or just the most common case(s). Worth an ask, I think.

Comment: Your best strategy is to get an official ruling and then decide.

Comment: @Buffy It's in code, too: https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/22/62.2 "Accompanying spouse and dependents. The alien spouse and/or minor unmarried child(ren), if any, of an exchange visitor who are accompanying or following to join the exchange visitor and who seek to enter or have entered the United States temporarily on non-immigrant J-2 visas or seek to acquire or have acquired such status after admission. For the purpose of these regulations, a minor is a person under the age of 21 years old."

Comment: https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/22/41.62 "J-2 Classification. The spouse or minor child of an alien classified J-1 is classifiable J-2."

Comment: This question seems more appropriate for expatriates.stackexchange.com than for academia.

Comment: Even if she got a visa, how do you afford to pay her health insurance? Health care cost is extremely high in US. One hospitalization could cost you several month salary. Your idea is extremely impractical.

Comment: A suggestion for you. Hire someone in India to take care of your mother. This would only cost a fraction of your postdoc salary.

Comment: @Nobody Then I may need to look for buying an International Health Plan from India as a tourist if I can't purchase one from the US. My mother requires mental and emotional support as well, so hiring someone may not be a great idea.

Comment: "_International Health Plan from India as a tourist_" is only for short term. I don't believe they sell the insurance for long term. If she stays longer than a month, you'll have to buy one in US.

Comment: @Nobody I have checked. 6 months of International Travel Insurance is feasible and it is pretty much affordable for an Indian (including vision and dental).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The possibility is extremely remote/near-impossible due to several reasons and complications abound at the different layers of scrutiny.

The J2 visa process begins with your university issuing a form DS-2019. It is extremely unlikely that a university can make an exception for your mother, without DHS (Department of Homeland Security) making a provision for such an exception. If there was such an exception, your university international student/exchange office would have let you known.

Universities do not and cannot risk making an exception when no such provision is offered from DHS. If they do, they run the risk of getting their SEVP approval cancelled.

On the extremely remote chance that your university does provide a DS-2019 to your mother, it is even more unlikely that a consular officer can get convinced to issue her a visa. Consular officers do understand the 'human' element but all human stories are evaluated in the light of what is already codified in their visa manuals.